# Reading n-length array separated by spaces

Tags: c#, console-application

Do you know a better way to take user input from the console? The first line of input consists of a single number n, which is the length of our array. Second-line has n numbers separated by spaces.
My code looks like this:

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[n];
string[] stringarray;
stringarray = Console.ReadLine()).Split(' ');
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(stringarray[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq instead of loop like this line:

```
arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(e => Convert.ToInt32(e)).ToArray();
```

Final Code:

```
int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
int[] arr = new int[n];
arr = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(e => Convert.ToInt32(e)).ToArray();
```